Normalizer of connected subgroup contained in the Weyl group?
Let $ G $ be a simple Lie group. Let $ H $ be a connected subgroup of $ G $ such that $ N(H)/H $ is finite. In such a case, is $ N(H)/H $ always a subgroup of the Weyl group of $ G $?
For $ G=\operatorname{SU}(2) $ the only nontrivial finite group $ N_G(H)/H $ is cyclic $ 2 $.
For $ G=\operatorname{SU}(3) $ the nontrivial finite groups $ N_G(H)/H $ are cyclic $ 3 $ and the symmetric group $ \mathrm{S}_3 $. For $ G=\operatorname{SO}(5) $ the nontrivial finite $ N_G(H)/H $ are cyclic $ 2 $ and $ \mathrm{D}_4 $. For $ G=\mathrm{G}_2 $ the only nontrivial finite groups $ N_G(H)/H $ are cyclic $ 2 $ and $ \mathrm{D}_6 $. So my guess seems right for all the rank $ 1 $ and $ 2 $ Lie groups.
Some more interesting examples are from Condition implying ()/
a Coxeter group? where the simple group $ \operatorname{GL}(3,2) $ of order $ 168 $ appears as $ N(H)/H $ for a connected subgroup $ H $ of $ E_7 $ and, as expected, seems to be a subgroup of the Weyl group $ W(E_7) $. Similarly, the affine group $ \operatorname{AGL}(3,2) $ of order $ 1344 $ appears as $ N(H)/H $ for a connected subgroup $ H $ of $ E_8 $ and, as expected, seems to be a subgroup of the Weyl group $ W(E_8) $.
This is crossposted from MSE.

Do you just mean whether $\operatorname N_G(H)/H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the Weyl group, or are you asking for something stronger?  (For example, do you impose any compatibility on $\operatorname N_G(T_G) \cap \operatorname N_G(H)$, where $T_G$ contains a maximal torus in $H$?)  \ Do you mean to take $H$ closed?  (Perhaps this is implied by $\operatorname N_G(H)/H$ being finite.)

@LSpice I just mean $ N_G(H)/H $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the Weyl group, but a compatibility condition on $ N_G(T_G) \cap N_G(H) $ sounds interesting! And I think $ N(H)/H $ finite is enough to show that $ H $ is closed, especially since I am assuming $ H $ connected.

Suppose $H$ is reductive and contains a Cartan subgroup $T$ of $G$. If $g\in N_G(H)$ then $gTg^{-1}$ is another Cartan subgroup of $H^0$, so $hg\in N_G(T)$ for some $h\in H$. I think this defines a group homomorphism $N_G(H)/H\rightarrow N_G(T)/T=W$. This applies to the $E_7$ and $E_8$ examples. I don't know what to do if this condition doesn't hold. Also I agree that the natural statement involves $N_G(T)\cap N_G(H)$.
